# omitting ''as to''

Tags: grammar, prepositions

in some sentences it is possible to omit ***''As to''***

For example;
A1)He was uncertain ***as to*** which road to take.

But , in some sentences it can not be omitted

EX;
B1)There's no decision ***as to*** when the work might start.

How can I tell which ''As to'' I cam omit , which one I can't?

Comment: Who told you 'as to' can't it be omitted in "There's no decision as to when the work might start."?

Comment: A British native speaker told me

Answer (score 1):

"As to" is often used as a kind of "extra preposition" before "whether", "when", "who", etc, and some grammarians have called this usage "absurd". If you take this view, both your A1 and B1 examples you gave do not need "as to". Using the phrase is generally best restricted to introducing a new subject, or returning to a subject that was mentioned only briefly before:

> As to the lab’s upcoming experiment, we’ll just have to wait and see.
>   As to the cost of living on the island, that’s something worth
>   investigating.

[As to](https://stancarey.wordpress.com/2008/08/30/as-to-as-to/)