# Can we always substitute prepositions with 'as to'?

Tags: prepositions

I found this interesting [discussion](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/192703/110852) about the usage of **as to**. The answerer wrote that this phrase is some kind of **extra preposition** before **wh-word**.

I don't comprehend what **extra** preposition means, by the way. Is it wise, if I'm starting to think that I can always substitute prepositions with this phrase like these examples even in formal writing:

> - Billy asked my advice (**on** / **as to**) what food he should eat first.
> - There was a debate (**on** / **as to**) which transport policy is not necessary.
> - I gave Lucy strict instructions (**about** / **as to**) how to tidy up her bedroom.

Comment: Are you only interested in replacements with prepositions? How about phrases like, "relating to" or "on the topic of"?

Comment: In my experience, this usage is popular among insecure office managers who think it makes them sound smart.

Comment: @gotube I'm interested in the replacement of the prepositions with **as to**, but if you want to provide explanations about "relating to" and "on the topic of" as well, I would love to know.

Comment: @user516076 If you explained why you're interested particularly in prepositions to replace "as to", like how this information would be useful to you, it would be easier for someone to give you a clear answer. As it stands, it's quite difficult for anyone to give you a verifiable answer that *every* instance of "as to" can be replaced by a preposition, so I don't see this question attracting any answers

Comment: @gotube I mean. For a learner like me, it's quite challenging to determine which prepositions that come after nouns. If someone can verify this thought, I'd use 'as to' whenever I use this construction to avoid confusion rather than using prepositions.

Comment: @user516076 Ah! In that case, I'm sorry to inform you that "as to" is rather formal and often sounds pretentious. I generally avoid it. Best to learn the meanings of the more common and natural preposition uses than trying to replace them all with "as to".